# How to tell my manager that I will leave if things don't change without offending him?

Tags: performance-reviews, leave

I'm a Web developer. My annual performance review is approaching. How can I tell my manager in a very professional way that I don't like the projects I have being working on at the company; If I'm not being assigned different projects, I will leave the company?

I like the rest of the team (7 web developers). I like my manager. I like the company. I'm underpaid compared to the market by at least 10K Canadian Dollars. I really don't like what I have being doing; neither it will benefit me in the career that I want for myself. And if you are wondering, most of the stuff I'm working on was not in the job description when I accepted the offer.

Comment: How well can you articulate what you do want in a project? How realistic is it for them to give you those kinds of projects for work? These are questions not answered in what you post and would likely be what you may get asked that if you can't answer you could be in trouble in a sense. After all, it isn't like you are picking up animal fecal matter as your current set of work tasks right?

Comment: Related: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/49652/how-to-give-a-polite-ultimatum

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, I wouldn't threaten to leave the company.

Let me explain.  During a performance review, you are (probably) going to be asked what you like and dislike about your year so far.  They usually ask you if you'd like to work on anything specific or just keep doing what you're doing.  Granted they might not ask those questions, but it would definitely be a place where you could talk to your manager and ask about what you can do, if you can get different projects this year, etc.  Just say you're wondering what projects they have in mind, and see if maybe you can suggest and/or push your manager a certain direction.

Telling him "if things don't change, I quit", will probably not put you in a great light, and might even jeopardize your job.  What I would do is make a list of the things you want to work on, ask your manager if any of the things you want to work on are feasible for the company and gauge his/her reaction.  If they don't or can't give you the projects you are looking for, then it's probably best to look for another job.

Obviously it'd be nice to give them a heads up, but it's not up to you to make sure their feelings aren't hurt, it's up to you to watch out for yourself.  The best you can do is make sure you give proper notice if you do find another job, and do everything you can to finish out the work you're on before leaving.  Leaving on good terms is nice, but it's not always up to you.

Comment: I agree.  I've had some success at my job getting switched to more interesting projects just by straight up telling my boss the stuff I was working on wasn't very engaging to me.  Best to have this conversation first and see if it leads anywhere before threatening to quit.  And if you are really underpaid and they know it (which they most likely do), they may specifically want to facilitate other non-monetary requests of yours to try to keep you from jumping ship to the better paying job.

Comment: +1, don't give ultimatums to management, they will quite often call you on it immediately as they can't afford to keep giving in.

Comment: @cdkMoose I would say it's the opposite. They - the company - can afford to replace you but you, normally, cannot afford to be out of a job.

Comment: @Dan, that was my point, they can afford to replace you and they are almost forced to let you go because they have to protect against the next ultimatum.

Answer (score 1):

I would request a meeting and ask your manager if there are any opportunities for the projects you are looking for. If he says no, you may need to just look for another job.