# Appropriate use of leverage

Tags: salary, promotion

I've been job hunting for a few weeks since getting stuck with a strange VP and being mislead with salary changes. I have a few offers that are starting to show up, but in the middle of all my interviewing, my Team Lead quit and I have been offered his job in six months (if I want it) by the CTO. The pay would be significant (38% raise), I think I could tolerate managing a few people, and my family is understanding about the higher workload.

Context:
- I think the "in six months" clause is meant to suggest that I'm almost skilled enough for that position. (e.g. I need to learn a few more things about our software to be a fully skilled Lead, etc.) - this is understandable, but I'm less understanding because of the next point.

- Last year, after four or five meetings with the CTO, he promised me an 18% raise and ended up giving me a 10% raise last month, as if he forgot or ignored the multiple references to the higher figure. I told him I needed a raise to stay where I was living, but that if he couldn't give me that much, that I would just move to a cheaper house, no big deal. Now I'm stuck renting a less affordable place when I should be saving for buying a house.

Because I don't fully trust my company as much after this issue, I'm wondering if I am justified in doing the following:

- Collecting all my offers and showing them to the CTO
- Telling him that he can make me a Lead now, with the full pay raise or I will leave in two weeks
- If he denies me, I will just go and work elsewhere

If I decide not to go forward with this plan, and they end up revoking the Lead position from me, I will have passed on a handful of comparable offers and will need to start the interview process all over again.

Is this a petty or overemotional reaction? I need some outside perspective on this issue to know the potential pitfalls.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to give a polite ultimatum?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/49652/how-to-give-a-polite-ultimatum)

Comment: Related: [Do I mention a competing offer when negotiating a raise?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/q/33457)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't trust management enough to take their word, why would you trust them that the position and raise you're being offered will remain stable six months from now? If you come across as emotional and demanding, they will probably do whatever it takes to settle the situation down in the short-term only to remove you as soon as they've found a more reliable replacement.

Answer (score 4):

1. They've already failed to live up to past promises.
2. If they're offering you this job, it makes no sense for them to wait 6 months. Something doesn't "smell right" to me.
3. You have no idea what may happen in the next 6 months. They might just as well find someone else for this position in that time.
4. Their past history doesn't bode well for them following through and making good on what they've told you.

If you like this company and want to stay then have a serious conversation about it and make sure to get verbal and written commitments for both the position and the salary.

Leverage, by it's very definition, is the application or exertion of force. You want to force them to do something that you want them to do, which they've shown you by their actions they're resistant to. This can't end well for you or them. If you're going to leave, then leave. Don't play games. There's no point in playing a negotiating game with them.

Comment: Totally agree with this answer. Why bother going with showing them other offers to get a raise when you already have other offers? Just take one! A small side note: Avoid giving an ultimatum of leaving in a few weeks if you don't already have a new job lined up. It's much better to bide your time and look for a good offer when you're still employed. Employers are more likely to offer you a role if you're already working, and you'll be flexible enough to turn down any mediocre offers.

Comment: Their offer definitely doesn't smell right. Unless the existing team lead is on 6 months' notice, their decision to delay making you team lead for 6 months makes no sense. If they think the team can function perfectly well without a team lead for 6 months, what reason would they ever have to promote you to that role (at a significant increase in salary)? Sounds like they suspect you're already looking and are trying to string you along without committing. Look for another role, once you have an offer, tell them. They may decide to then make a counter offer, but don't accept an empty promise.